# Reopening "Customers by orders Total Only Shows 5"

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I voted to reopen the below question. Here's my reasoning:

- It is regarding the Magento admin panel reports
- It asks why a report behaves a certain way
- It can have a single, canonical answer

Because of the above I feel that it fits well into the format of this site. If it were asked *why the developers chose* to make it work a certain way it would be off-topic, the question is asking how to extend the report. I will attempt to answer myself.

In the meantime any thoughts from the community on why this may or may not belong?

[Customers by Orders Total only shows 5](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82033/customers-by-orders-total-only-shows-5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have opened another question in response to this one which I feel better represents what happened here - pileon close votes.

**Please lend your feedback over here:**

[Let's review our guidelines for "off topic"](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700/lets-review-our-guidelines-for-off-topic)

Answer (score 1):

I still feel it as an off-topic, since it is not clear for me.

The depicted behaviour may cause due to customization in the site. No hint about any customization that done to the site. Without seeing the code, I suspect it will be difficult to help him out. Again this is my personal opinion.

If the question is clear for you, then we are waiting for your answer so that you can clearly justify your act.

Thanks phil

### Edit

I would also like to mention that, I had such situations before. Questions which were closed as off-topic seems relevant and clear for me. In those cases, I immediately contacted moderators and let them know about that. In most of the cases, moderators will immediately open the question for us, if we let them know that we really want to answer that question.

It is good to see that, being a moderator you came forward to discuss a question that you have opened with proper reasoning. You can do that without having a prior notice to anyone. Much appreciated. Kudos.

But we are expecting an answer from your part, so that the thread in this question no longer remain un-answered (I think a re-opened question will not come on the top of Magento recent activity page. So there is no-way to follow this change !!).

Comment: This is a built in report and it does, indeed, only show the top five sorted by revenue descending. Editing this behavior is a bit tricky and may help some understand Magento deeper. Therefore the purpose and tone of this is very clear to me.

Comment: @philwinkle  please see the edit.

Comment: The answer is now live on the question.